# Tensorflow - Confusion matrix with half zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow, imblearn

I'm trying to create a *tensorflow* model that predicts fraudulent transactions (in my dataset, 99.8% of transactions are normal and only 0.2% are fraudulent).
I have only three columns :

- Time
- Amount
- Class
  And I try to predict the class (0 for normal transactions ; 1 for fraudulent ones).

But, when I compute the confusion matrix, here is my result :

```
array([[227459,      0],
       [   387,      0]], dtype=int64)
```

My data is stored into X, y.

I start by splitting my data :

```
#Create three separate splits (Train, Val, Test)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.95, random_state=42)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#Rebalance the training set
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X_train, y_train = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

Then, I create the model and fit it :

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Normalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(25, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["Precision", "Recall", "AUC"])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=100)
```

Also, here are things that I import :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import imblearn
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules import ExponentialDecay
```

Can someone help me, please ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You should think about what using softmax activation with a single unit actually does.

Comment: Change your activation function for the last layer from `softmax` to `sigmoid` as you are doing a binary classification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I replaced "softmax" by "sigmoid" but I still have a problem. Then, I edited my question.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is actually fraudulent data on your training, from the 387 test fraudulent samples (that come from 95% of the dataset, your train/validation sets share only ~20 samples (compared to around 12k transaction samples). Even with SMOTE that might not be enough

Comment: Also, there might be actually not enough information in "time" and "amount" to define a model that can distinguish fraud from normal... Your data is simple (2D), check if the frauds stand out from the normal samples in any way, if they don't, there is no amount of NN layers that can create that information from scratch. You would have to look into sequences of transactions to get some context information

Comment: However, it is still strange that I have two zeros and not even 100 or 200... ?